# No entiendo varias cosas de esta consulta

Tags: mysql

Principalmente lo que no entiendo es esas letras que esta al lado de cada campo ejemplo 's'.'name_subject'.
Me podrian explicar porfavor Gracias!!

```
 SELECT `s`.`name_subject`, `s`.`code_subject`, `s`.`credits`, `ps`.`trimester`, `s`.`component` FROM `validations_process` AS `vp` JOIN `templates` AS `t` ON `vp`.`id_template` = `t`.`id_template` JOIN `programs_subjects` AS `ps` ON `ps`.`id_program` = `t`.`id_program` JOIN `subjects` AS `s` ON `ps`.`id_subject` = `s`.`id_subject` WHERE `vp`.`id_homologate_request` = '72' AND ps.id_subject NOT IN (SELECT id_subject FROM subject_interchanges si, validations_process vp, templates t where vp.id_template = `t`.`id_template` AND `vp`.`id_homologate_request` = '72') AND `ps`.`trimester` != '0' ORDER BY `ps`.`trimester` ASC
```

Comment: El alias que se le dio a la tabla y la columna elegida de dicha tabla

Comment: entiendo muchas gracias

Comment: @AndredGarciaMartin en tu pregunta dice "no entiendo varias cosas de esta consulta", una de ellas es el `AS` hay otras mas? Y si es asi, [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/417710/edit) tu pregunta poniendo las cosas que no entiendes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces una consulta, a las tablas le puedes colocar un nombre de referencia que es solo para la consulta que estas ejecutando. ej:

```
SELECT
per.nombre_personal 
FROM personal AS per;
```

En el caso que estas viendo es por una tabla que viene por JOIN
un ejemplo de esto sería:

```
SELECT 
loc.nombre_local, 
per.nombre_personal
FROM local AS loc
INNER JOIN personal AS per
ON loc.id = per.id_local_actual
WHERE loc.nombre_local = "Local 1"
```

Como se puede ver se está trabajando la tabla `local` como `loc` y `personas` como `per`

Answer (score 2):

Estas letras corresponden al alias que le das a la tabla, por ejemplo `subjects` AS `s`, indicas que la tabla subjects tiene el alias s. Al indicar `s`.`name_subject` estás consultando el campo name_subject de la tabla subject.